# Wordpress wp_update_user only updates after refresh

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a custom page in my Wordpress installation which, among other things, allows a user to **display** and **change** their email address from the front-end.

When they do, though, the email gets correctly changed in the DB, but is not updated on the page until another *refresh* (with or without a `$_POST`). This behaviour is really weird and I can't find the cause.

Here is the problematic part of code:

```
if ( !empty( $_POST['user_email'] ) )
    wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $queried_user->id, 'user_email' => esc_attr( $_POST['user_email'] ) ) ) ;
```

If I execute `var_dump($_POST)` and `var_dump($queried_user)`, I get that `user_email` is correctly displayed in the `$_POST` variable, but, accordingly, remains the old one in the `$queried_user` variable. Looking at the DB through PHPMyAdmin, though, I can see that the data has already been updated. After another refresh of the browser page, everything displays correctly.

Any pointers?

Comment: P.S. Forgot to mention: I update many other parameters in the same page, and they all refresh correctly on first page post. I should mention, though, that I update them through the use of `update_user_meta`. As `user_email` is stored in the wp_users table it is the only thing I really need to update using the said function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how you are populating $queried_user, but try this:

```
if ( !empty( $_POST['user_email'] ) )
{
   $queried_user->user_email=$_POST['user_email'];
   wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $queried_user->id, 'user_email' => esc_attr( $queried_user->user_email ) ) ) ;
}
```

Comment: I populate `$queried_user` like this `get_userdata(intval($_REQUEST['id']))`.

Thank you a lot, it works like charm. What is the rationale behind this working if you don't mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: Your $queried_user variable does not auto-magically get updated when you do wp_update_user.  You have to either specifically set the value, or reload it using get_userdata.  Hope that makes sense.  Glad you got working.

Comment: Thanks @Gary, your solution helped after a couple of hours